# Splitting a line into token with find()

Tags: c++, split, find

I want to split this line :

`cmd1; cmd2; cmd3`

Into 3 strings I will stock into a list. like

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

So I made this code :

`main.cpp`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int     main()
{
  std::string   line("cmd1; cmd2; cmd3");
  std::list<std::string>        l;
  size_t        pos = 0;
  size_t        ex_pos = 0;

  while ((pos = line.find(';', ex_pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
      l.push_back(line.substr(ex_pos, pos));
      ex_pos = pos + 2;
    }
  l.push_back(line.substr(ex_pos, pos));
  for (std::list<std::string>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
    {
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
  return (0);
}
```

But I don't know why it returns me :

```
cmd1
cmd2; cmd3
cmd3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument of `substr` is not an index of lat character to copy. It is length of target substring.

```
l.push_back(line.substr(ex_pos, pos-ex_pos));
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Oh yeah totally, I'm so dumb, thanks a lot !
I'll 'accept' your answer in 6 mins :)

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [std::basic_string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) expects a length, indicating the length of the substring starting from start_pos.

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

So, you should actually replace

```
l.push_back(line.substr(ex_pos, pos));
```

with

```
l.push_back(line.substr(ex_pos, pos - ex_pos));
```